# Audio File Field is empty (null) on drupalgap app

Tags: 7, javascript

What i want to do is create/view podcast node type inside DrupalGap App in Android.
I am using drupal 7 on Centos 7. 
drupal module: audiofield (https://www.drupal.org/project/audiofield)
drupalgap module added on www\app\modules: audiofield (http://drupalgap.org/project/audiofield)
I am using HTML 5 player (default). But also tried before jplayer.

On content type named podcast i have fields:
title, body and
audio file with File (as type) and Audio Upload (as widget).

Permission given:
Audio: Download own files
Audio: Download All Audio Files
Media->Use the media browser
Podcast: Create new content
Podcast: Edit own content
Podcast: Delete own content

even i gave:
Add and upload new files
View own private files
View own files
Audio: Edit own files
Audio: Delete own files
Audio: Download any files

In browser i can listen and download and create new Podcast. All work well.
In my android app (drupalgap) when viewing, i can see a player but nothing happens when i press play or download button. And when i try to create a podcast in the audio file field, DrupalGap shows Null and nothing else below.

P.S. I can provide test account if need be

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the url of the source audio file was wrong. It happened after i deleted originalsong.mp3 and reuploaded it. So, system gave it new name originalsong_0.mp3 (Note the _0 at the end of the filename). Probably drupal keeps track of files uploaded even when they are deleted so when i upload same mp3 with same filename it gets _0, _1 etc.
Null object appears at www.example.com/mobile-application but when project is compiled and run in real Android device it works out of the box. Play button works but not Download button(minor problem for me).